About a surface connected
Let $S$ be a connected surface. In many propositions, exercises, etc., I have seen that if the surface is connected, given any point $p \in S$, then there exists a parametrization of the surface from a connected set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ into $V$, where $V$ is an open nbhd of $p$ in $S$ satisfying all the assumptions of the definition of a parametrization.
Why can I choose $U$ being connected? Thank you for your help.

I think what you are referring to are just from the definition of a chart on a manifold. Assuming you're talking about a smooth manifold, you have a homoemorphism or diffeomorphism from the open set to $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ is connected.

Adding onto Sam's comment, you also don't need to assume $S$ is connected. Every manifold is locally connected, so if you have a chart around $p$ you can always restrict to a connected neighborhood of $p$ to get the diffeomorphism you want.
